# How to replace (encode) multi values based on value ranges in one column?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to change values in a column based on its range, how should I do it?

here is a sample dataset

```
Id    Number

0      2
1      2
2      2
3      2
4     23
5      6
6     16
7     10
8     15
9      8
10     6
11     9
12     1

Here is the range:

   if number >=6 and <12 then 1
   if number ==12, then 2
   if number >=13 and <=17, then 3
   if number >17 and <=22 then 4
   else 5
```

How should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use NumPy's [`select()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
import numpy as np

np.select([
    df.Number.between(6, 11),
    df.Number == 12,
    df.Number.between(13, 17),
    df.Number.between(18, 22)],
    [1, 2, 3, 4], 5)
```

Comment: Zwick many thanks. I just ran it. The number did not change. I will try it again. Thank you. Will let you know, if it does not work

Comment: @almo: The code I wrote does not modify the data structure, it produces a new array which you need to store somewhere.  P.S. why do people always leave the "n" out of my name?

Comment: @thanks, now it shows. Is there any way to use replace, map, etc? Just would like to see if there is any other approaches to solve it.  I accepted your answer:)